# How to test event in StencilJS component

Tags: stenciljs

I have a StencilJS component with an Event defined as:

```
@Event({eventName: 'focusEvent'}) focusEvent: EventEmitter<any>;
```

And the component looks like this:

```
<input type='text' 
    ... 
    onFocus={ (evt) => this.focusEvent.emit(evt)}>           
</input>
```

My test is as follows:

```
const mockEvent = jest.fn();
const page = await newE2EPage();
await page.setContent(`<my-textbox focusEvent=${mockEvent}></my-textbox>`);

await page.waitForSelector('input');
const el = await page.find('input');
expect(el).not.toBeNull();     // <-- this passes
       
const spy = el.spyOnEvent("focusEvent");
await el.focus();
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();   // <-- this fails
```

The error is:

```
Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

    Received has type:  object
    Received has value: {}
```

If I put the component in a test application and run it, I can see that the focus event fires when I click into the text box, but I can't figure out how to reproduce that in a test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
 const page = await newE2EPage();
 await page.setContent(`<my-textbox></my-textbox>`); // removed the focusEvent={...}
    
 const input = await page.find('input') // removed the waitForSelector + find, just find works 

 expect(input).not.toBeNull();     // <-- this passes

 const focusEventSpy = await page.spyOnEvent('focusEvent');

 await input.focus();

 await page.waitForChanges(); // introduced the wait for changes

 expect(focusEventSpy).toHaveReceivedEvent();   // <-- this now passes
```

Key points:

- `waitForChanges`, from stenciljs docs:

> Both Stencil and Puppeteer have an asynchronous architecture, which is
> a good thing for performance. Since all calls are async, it's required
> that await page.waitForChanges() is called when changes are made to
> components.

- use of the find method ([Stencil#FindElementsInDOM](https://stenciljs.com/docs/end-to-end-testing#example-end-to-end-test), [Stencil#FindElementsInShadowDOM](https://stenciljs.com/docs/end-to-end-testing#find-an-element-in-the-shadow-dom))

Comment: Thanks @FelipeMalara.  This worked, but I have 2 questions: (1) I can't find documentation on 'toHaveReceivedEvent' anywhere.  Do you know where I can read more about it?  (2) I'm setting up the spy on the _page_ not the input component.  Why does that work when the input is focused?  Is it just because the event bubbles up?   Any additional insight to help me understand why this works would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: Hey @TimTheEnchanter. Yeah, you absolute right abt the 2 questions, (1): the `toHaveReceivedEvent` is nowhere on the documentation (hope they add on the next couple months), but it can be found [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/blob/main/src/declarations/stencil-private.ts#L2175) and if you have @stencil/core installed, it should appear the autocomplete hints pointing to it in your IDE. (2) Yeah, you are tracking it on the page because it bubbles up, it worth trying `spyOnEvent` in a parent element instead of the page.